# Wrong order of elements when appending to .csv

Tags: python, selenium

Here is a sample of my current code

```
for i in pin:

    i.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    f = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="bold"]')
    d = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="date"]')
    with open("tennisopening.csv","a") as r:
        r.write(match + "," + date + "," + score + "\n")

        for i in f:

            b= i.text

            for i in d:

                c= i.text

                with open("tennisopening.csv","a") as r:
                    r.write(b + "," + c)
```

This results in a csv table with cells in the following order:

(b,c,match,date,score,\n)

But, I wish to have it in the following order:

(match,date,score,b,c,\n)

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want your csv to include "match,date,score" in every line or just first line?

Comment: Included for every line

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in pin:

i.click()
time.sleep(4)
f = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="bold"]')
d = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="date"]')
with open("tennisopening.csv","a") as r:
    for i in f:
        b= i.text
        for i in d:
            c= i.text
            with open("tennisopening.csv","a") as r:
                r.write(b + "," + c)
    r.write(match + "," + date + "," + score + "\n")
```

This will do

Remember when u write using

```
with open(filename,mode) as f:
     f.write(data)
     ## data is written only in memory and not yet committed to file.
## data now committed to file
```

so for the data to be written you must come out of `with open()` scope

same goes for above data

First come out of this with's scope

```
with open("tennisopening.csv","a") as r:
    r.write(b + "," + c)
```

and then write into memory

```
r.write(match + "," + date + "," + score + "\n")
```

Then come out of parent with scope

;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your inner loop code with this:

```
with open("tennisopening.csv","a") as r:
    for i in f:
        b= i.text
        for i in d:
            c= i.text
            r.write("{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(match,date,score,b,c)
```

This should write "match,date,score,b,c\n" in every line as you asked.

In your code, (match, date, score) will be written only once for every outer loop code.

And you have two instances open for the same file, the instance which writes "b,c" closes first, so it gets written first in the actual file.